# Spring-Kafka: RecordIntercepter class not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am using spring boot 2.1.5 and spring-kafka, version not specified. Project is gradle 6.0, java 1.8

I am getting this error

```
error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.kafkaannotationdrivenconfiguration': unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.typenotpresentexception: type org.springframework.kafka.listener.recordinterceptor not present
```

What could be this due to? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.1.5 is nearly a year old; the current Boot 2.1.x release is 2.1.13.

2.1.5 uses spring-kafka 2.2.6 so I don't see how you can get that error, based on your description.

`RecordInterceptor` was added in spring-kafka 2.2.7.

It was [added to the Spring Boot autoconfiguration in 2.2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/eeda12bd58c2b49e6a053fc545eade7168c0ff1f).

So what you are describing makes no sense; you must be using Boot 2.2.x and an old spring-kafka version.

You have mis-matched Boot/Kafka versions.

Upgrade to Boot 2.1.13 (or preferably 2.2.6).

Comment: You are right. I am sorry. I double checked our deployed image. Due to some tagging mistake some old was getting pulled wherein spring-kafka version was old